# ZSH alias definition and expansion within eval string

Tags: eval, alias, zsh

I came across a curiosity when playing around whilst learning ZSH, and i'm having a hard type finding information related to this. I was wondering about the technical explanation of why this doesn't work (defining and then expanding an alias within a single eval call):

```
eval "alias d='echo hello'; d"

zsh: command not found: d
```

whereas this does work:

```
eval "function d = { echo hello; }; d"

hello
```

Answer (score 5):

`eval` has nothing to do with the issue. Calling just

```
alias d='echo hello'; d
```

will not work either.

The reason for that lies in the way zsh parses a command line. All aliases in a command line are substituted *before* zsh even tries to execute it. In this example zsh does not know about the alias `d` when the aliases are substituted and so zsh comes up empty when looking for the command `d`.

The example with the function on the other hand works, because zsh looks up where a command name points just before it tries to run it. So first the function `d` is defined and when zsh encounters the command `d` it looks for a matching function (or built-in or external command) and finds the previously defined function.